# Where did AndroidModuleModel.findProductFlavor go? My plugin throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, android-studio-4.2, android-studio-plugin

I'm the author of [this](https://github.com/Nilzor/build-variant-matrix) build variant plugin, and from Android Studio 4.1 to 4.2.1, a method I depend on seems to have been removed from the IDE API: `ProductFlavorContainer com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.findProductFlavor(String)`

In the master branch for the source code for the android plugin of IDEA, it *seems* to still [be there though](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/model/AndroidModuleModel.java#L401)! What's going on here?

The concrete exception I'm getting is on [this line](https://github.com/Nilzor/build-variant-matrix/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nilsenlabs/flavormatrix/actions/AndroidModuleHelper.kt#L36), with this text:

```
llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 'com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavorContainer com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.findProductFlavor(java.lang.String)' 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.android.builder.model.ProductFlavorContainer com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.findProductFlavor(java.lang.String)'
at com.nilsenlabs.flavormatrix.actions.AndroidModuleHelper.createMergedDimensionList(AndroidModuleHelper.kt:38)
```

My build environment is IntelliJ IDEA community edition 2020.2.4, Build #IC-202.8194.7

The original target version was Android Studio version 193.6911.18

I've tried updating the target version to 202.7660.26 (Android Studio 4.2.1) to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method had been replaced with new signature:

```
public IdeProductFlavorContainer findProductFlavor(@NotNull String name)
```

The problem was getting IDEA to resolve that class when no new IDEA target library had been published for Android Studio 4.2.x. Solution: in `build.gradle` target your local installation by using `intellij.localPath` instead of `intellij.version`

Thanks to Kuznetsov at Jetbrains in [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010869300-Where-did-AndroidModuleModel-findProductFlavor-go-My-plugin-throws-NoSuchMethodError)